# Map async result with automapper

Tags: c#, async-await, automapper

We are createing a Web.Api application of a angularjs application. The Web.Api returns a json result.

Step one was getting the data:

```
    public List<DataItem>> GetData()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<List<DataItem>>(dataRepository.GetData());
    }
```

That worked like a charm. Then we made the data repo async and we changed to code to work with it.

```
    public List<DataItem>> GetData()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<List<DataItem>>(dataRepository.GetDataAsync().Result);
    }
```

Stil no problems. Now we wanted to make my Web.Api full async awayt so we changed it to:

```
    public async Task<List<DataItem>> GetData()
    {
        return await Mapper.Map<Task<List<DataItem>>>(dataRepository.GetDataAsync());
    }
```

At this moment Automapper gets confused. First we had the following mapper rule:
         Mapper.CreateMap();

This worked until the web api method became full async. The exception said it was missing a map from

```
 Task<ICollection<Data>> to Task<ICollection<DataItem>>.
```

The mapper was changed to

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Task<List<Data>>, Task<List<DataItem>>>();
```

When validating the configuration it complains that Result cannot be mapped. How should we configure the mappings?

Comment: could you change to: `var data = await dataRepository.GetDataAsync(); return Mapper.Map<List<DataItem>>(data);`? Similar to what is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827417/map-async-model-collection-to-async-viewmodel-collection

Comment: But then the controller itself is not async anymore?

Comment: The method will be marked async and contains the await within the body so you won't lose your mapping and still async

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to move the async data fetch out of the Map call:

```
var data = await dataRepository.GetDataAsync();
return Mapper.Map<List<DataItem>>(data);
```

Alternatively, you can use AutoMapper LINQ projections:

```
var data = await dbContext.Data.ProjectTo<DataItem>().ToListAsync();
```

I don't know if your repository exposes IQueryable directly (we don't use repositories). Our apps use the second version pretty much exclusively these days.

Comment: We are using repositories to wrap MongoDB. The repositories give back a list<T> that need to be mapped to our viewmodels (to limit data pushed to the frontend). As far as I understood, MongoDB always give back the documents, so if you do projection it is done in the application.

Comment: @jimmy-bogard, what about this? ;) `_licenceRepository.Include(l => l.LicenceType).SingleOrDefaultAsync(ConditionLambda).ContinueWith(source => _mapper.Map<LicenceDto>(source.Result))`

Comment: I tried your first way and it worked for me, thank you!

Comment: Just something to consider; adding .Result to the end of any async calls

Answer (score 5):

Jose's solution proved quite useful to me.  I did, however, re-target the extension method to extend IMapper which allowed me to remove the singleton Mapper reference.

```
public static class MapperExtensions
{
    public static Task<TResult> MapAsync<TSource, TResult>(this IMapper mapper, Task<TSource> task)
    {
        if (task == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(task));
        }

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();

        task
            .ContinueWith(t => tcs.TrySetCanceled(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

        task
            .ContinueWith
            (
                t =>
                {
                    tcs.TrySetResult(mapper.Map<TSource, TResult>(t.Result));
                },
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion
            );

        task
            .ContinueWith
            (
                t => tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception),
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted
            );

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also add a couple of Task Extension Methods that will do this for you:

```
    public static Task<TReturn> Convert<T, TReturn>(this Task<T> task)
    {
        if (task == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(task));

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TReturn>();

        task.ContinueWith(t => tcs.TrySetCanceled(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(Mapper.Map<T, TReturn>(t.Result));
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        task.ContinueWith(t => tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        return tcs.Task;
    }


    public static Task<List<TReturn>> ConvertEach<T, TReturn>(this Task<List<T>> task)
    {
        if (task == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(task));

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<TReturn>>();

        task.ContinueWith(t => tcs.TrySetCanceled(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(t.Result.Select(Mapper.Map<T, TReturn>).ToList());
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        task.ContinueWith(t => tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this issue as well. I wanted to keep the async part of the method and therefore, I ended up with a solution that would wrap the await operation inside an async task.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ProjectDTO>> GetProject(long id)
        {
             return await Task<ProjectDTO>.Run(
                async () => {
                        var project = await _context.MDb.FindAsync(id);
                        return _mapper.Map<ProjectDTO>(project);            
                }
            );
        }
```

I would love to hear your thoughts/comments.