# Using AutoMapper to map a business entity to a list of Razor Page view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, razor-pages

I am using Razor Pages and I am confused how to map from Business Entity to view model using AutoMapper.

For example:

I have a business entity called: Product. My page ultimately needs a list of IndexModel. I want to use AutoMapper to map from IList Product to IList IndexModel.

Or should I still just be using a ViewModels folder with a bunch of ViewModels? I was able to get it working this way.

This works:

```
public IList<ProductIndexViewModel> Products { get;set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var productsFromDb = await _productRepository.GetAllAsync();
    Products = _mapper.Map<IList<ProductIndexViewModel>>(productsFromDb);
}
```

This does not

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set;}
// public IList<ProductIndexViewModel> Products { get;set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var productsFromDb = await _productRepository.GetAllAsync();
    Products = _mapper.Map<IList<this>>(productsFromDb);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify whether you are not sure about how to use automapper, which you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635534/simple-automapper-example); or you just don't know how to do the iteration, which can be solved by `.Select()`

Comment: The mapper transforms your result set `productsFromDb` a `IList<Product>` into the return set `IList<IndexModel>`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32616686/2030565.

Comment: When I pass auto mapper "this" it doesn't like it. @Jasen please see the update at the bottom of my post.

Comment: replace "this" with the PageModel type, I would highly suggest keeping your first implementation though, using a separate view model

Comment: @mxmissile I think that is where my misunderstanding is happening. See how I have two properties Id and Name? Isn't that my page model?

Comment: What is the problem with your first example that "works"?

Comment: @Jasen with Razor pages you shouldn't need a view model since there is a page model. So I want to try and get things working without a View model.

Comment: You are correct, however, to keep it separate allows reuse and also wont come with the payload of all the built in Page model members, most wont function anyway outside of the original context. Read about Separation of Concerns.

Comment: If you do not want a "View Model" why are you projecting the entity to a new type? The goal is to hide the Entity model and present the View Model instead. The page model is the VM. AutoMapper in this context, projects the Entity to a VM and you present this as the page model.

Comment: @Jasen didn't think of it that way until now. So my ViewModel class is fine since it is being used as the Page model? I guess what I was trying to do was avoid creating the ViewModel class and just set properties directly as the page model.

Comment: The reason the first works and the second doesn't is because when you pass generic type parameters, you must pass a type. You do that in the first, but you are passing an instance of a type in the second attempt. Boom.