# How to call awaitable method on AutoMapper Profile

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, automapper

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using AutoMapper to map objects between different layers of my application. In one of my AutoMapper profiles, I need to call an async method to retrieve some additional data before performing the mapping. However, it seems that AutoMapper profiles don't directly support asynchronous methods.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public class Profile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public Profile(ISequence sequence)
    {
        CreateMap<UserDto, User>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, options => options.MapFrom(async src => await sequence.GetNext()));
    }
}
```

I called async method just to demonstrate what exactly I want to acheive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map async result with automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609607/map-async-result-with-automapper)

Answer (score 1):

AutoMapper profiles don't support async methods in the MapFrom expression. This is because AutoMapper is designed to be a synchronous library that performs mapping operations in memory. If you need to call an async method to get some additional data, you have a few options:

•  You can use the AfterMap method to perform an async operation after the mapping is done. This method accepts an Action<TSource, TDestination> delegate that can be marked as async. For example:

```
public class Profile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
 public Profile(ISequence sequence)
  {
   CreateMap<UserDto, User>().ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, options => options.Ignore())
.AfterMap(async (src, dest) => dest.UserId = await sequence.GetNext());
  }
}
```

•  You can use the ProjectTo method to create a LINQ projection that can be executed asynchronously by the underlying data provider. This method allows you to use async methods in the Select expression. For example:

```
var users = await context.UserDtos
.ProjectTo<User>(configuration, src => sequence.GetNext())
.ToListAsync();
```

•  You can use a custom value resolver that implements the IValueResolver<TSource, TDestination, TDestMember> interface and has an async Resolve method. For example:

```
public class UserIdResolver : IValueResolver<UserDto, User, int>
{
private readonly ISequence _sequence;

public UserIdResolver(ISequence sequence)
{
   _sequence = sequence;
}

public async Task<int> Resolve(UserDto source, User destination, int destMember, ResolutionContext context)
 {
   return await _sequence.GetNext();
 }
}

public class Profile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
 public Profile(ISequence sequence)
  {
   CreateMap<UserDto, User>().ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, options => options.MapFrom(new UserIdResolver(sequence)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you have `async void` here and that's a problem.

Comment: No, it returns an int value type, not void.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct, I had the same problem as you and it worked for me.

Comment: That `await` is meaningless because you cannot await the `Map` call. _All_ `async` code must be _outside_ the `Map` call.